# remote_addr= method doesn't work in integration tests. What for this method is needed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, integration-testing

I'm doing integration tests in Rails. I want to imitate a request from an arbitrary ip address. So far I've learned that there are two ways to do it:

```
remote_addr=(remote_ip) ## the first
get("/", nil, {"REMOTE_ADDR" => "999.99.99"}) ## the second
```

But the first one doesn't work in integration tests. It doesn't set `remote_addr`:

```
test("some integration test") do
   r_a = "999.99.99"

   puts remote_addr
     remote_addr=(r_a)  ## neither before get()...
   puts remote_addr

   get("/")  ## get request

     remote_addr=(r_a)  ## nor after get() it doesn't set remote_addr

   assert_equal(r_a, assigns(:r_a))  ## assertion test 
end
```

Now I run the test. This is a result. Please pay attention that the value changes before and after:

```
# Running tests:

127.0.0.1
999.99.99
F

Finished tests in 1.109375s, 0.9014 tests/s, 5.4085 assertions/s.

  1) Failure:
test_some_integration_test(UserFlowsTest) [test/integration/user_flows_test.rb:45]:
<"999.99.99"> expected but was
<"127.0.0.1">.
```

But as I said above the second approach works fine:

```
test("some integration test") do
   r_a = "999.99.99"

   puts remote_addr
     get("/", nil, {"REMOTE_ADDR" => "999.99.99"})
   puts remote_addr

   assert_equal(r_a, assigns(:r_a))  ## assertion test

   puts "assigns(:r_a) = #{assigns(:r_a)}"
end
```

The result. Please pay attention that the value isn't changed in `remote_addr()` but is changed in `assigns(:r_a)`:

```
# Running tests:

127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1
assigns(:r_a) = 999.99.99
.

Finished tests in 1.296875s, 0.7711 tests/s, 7.7108 assertions/s.
```

The source code of [remote_addr=](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/TestRequest.html#method-i-remote_addr-3D) is this:

```
# File actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/testing/test_request.rb, line 55
def remote_addr=(addr)
  @env['REMOTE_ADDR'] = addr
end
```

It has to change, but it doesn't.

1. Why `remote_addr=` doesn't set the remote_ip in integration tests?
2. What for then this method is needed?
3. Is it still possible to use it in integration tests or the second approach is the only option?

Answer (score 2):

Since I've written quite much in the question, I post some update here.

DO NOT use **[follow_redirect!()](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Integration/RequestHelpers.html#method-i-follow_redirect-21)** in integration test if your integration test have action redirects (e.g. from `create` action `reditect_to("show")` action) AND you imitate a request from arbitrary IPs (`env['REMOTE_ADDR']`). So you want to keep the same `remote_addr` in both actions.

`follow_redirect!()` doesn't persist `env['REMOTE_ADDR']` setting. `env['REMOTE_ADDR']` is reset in the redirected_to action.

Instead use [request_via_redirect()](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Integration/RequestHelpers.html#method-i-get_via_redirect) method. This way, for example:

```
# your redirection assertion...
assert_response(:redirect)

# is followed by this
request_via_redirect("GET", 
   url_for(:action => "show", :id => assigns(:model).id), 
   nil,
   {"REMOTE_ADDR" => "999.99.99"})
```

With this method you can forward your `env['REMOTE_ADDR']` setting to the next action.